# Internal IP disclosure Worklight/WebSphere

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have an issue where the Worklight server is disclosing an Internal IP in its header.

In the Host : A.B.C.D is showing our internal IP server.

[image]

How can we resolve this issue, or is there any configuration in the server that needs to be applied ?

Answer (score 0):

eI see a paramter called $WSRH: where does it come from ? since this one contains the IP. was it defined somewhere in the worklight.properties (or as JNDI property (some people use it later as adapter parameter)?

However, I believe you original question is about "Host" cookie value.
maybe this will help:
examine your worklight.properties (also packed into the project WAR file)
you can define there: publicWorkLightHostname

Comment: "Host" has an IP value and not cookie value, and it contains one of our servers IP address. My worklight.properties doesn't contain and definition for any server value or host name. disclosing an internal IP in the header is an issue.